# Как разбить строку на символы в двумерном списке python

Tags: python, строки, list

У меня есть список `mas`. Мне нужно, чтобы каждый подсписок из одной строки стал списком из символов.

```
n = int(input())
mas = []
for i in range(n):
    nt = int(input())
    for j in range(nt):
        mas.append(list(map(str, input().split())))
print(mas)
```

Comment: Какая проблема с текущим кодом?

Comment: @Эникейщик он выдает данные в формате [['000'], ['111'], ['222']]. Надо чтобы выдавал данные в формате [['0', '0', '0'], ['1', '1', '1'], ['2', '2', '2']]

Comment: Убери split, зачем он там?

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо! Без сплита работает

Comment: Да и map в этом случае не надо. ``list(input())`` достаточно.